# MySQL select all and start from a specific id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image

Is there a method that calls all rows into a database and start from a specific id? 
For example:

I create an images gallery and each images have as "onclick" this function getimage(userid,imageid);

With ajax's json method call every photos by userid but this ever start from the first row.
So with second condition "imageid" i could run the animation from that point but i don't know if exist a similiar method.

Condition would be perfect if it were like this:

```
$query = "SELECT url as href FROM post WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND type = 'photo' START FROM $imageid";
```

There is something?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT url as href FROM post WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND type = 'photo' and image_ID >= $imageid";
```

Please note that you need to adjust the fieldname to the one mathcing your table.

If you want to get all the images from the database, but start showing them from the provided ID, you'll have to loop through the returned results and store them in a tmp array untill you hit the provided ID. The rest you then add to the output array. in the end, you perform an array_merge to get the first images added to the end of the array.

Comment: Greater than or equal to ;)

Comment: It loads previous image or start only from that pont ?

Comment: It loads images with the passed ID or with an ID greater than the one passed. Please note that you need to adjust the fieldname to the one mathcing your table.

Comment: I tried it and it works but does not load the previous ones, How could I also load these ones ?

Answer (score 1):

Use "greater than or equal".

Assuming that the column is `image_id` and `image_id` and `user_id` are integers your query should look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT url as href FROM post WHERE user_id = $user_id AND type = 'photo' AND image_id >= $imageID";
```

**Be aware that your script is probably wide open to sql-injections if you do not escape the values you are inserting.**

Comment: It works but does not load the previous ones, How could I also load these ones ?

Comment: I thought you only want to load the images where the image_id is `greater than or equals`. If you want to load the previous ones too remove the last condition or modify it to your needs?!

Comment: mmm... ok :D i will find something

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for the problem.
Basically, I make two arrays with two different query.

- First one searchs only images with id greater than or equal to image
  selected.
- Second one searching for the previuos images.
- Than i merge two arrays with magical
  `array_merge($firstarray,$secondarray)` and add `'cyclic': true` to
  fancybox options.

That's it ;D it works perfecly.